# Does rails 3.1 include the entire jQuery library?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.1, coffeescript, asset-pipeline

I have been really puzzled because I was trying to work out some jQuery tutorials in coffeescript for rails 3.1 and it seems like none of the animation functions of jquery work.

For example, this does nothing:

`/assets/javascripts/my_controller.js.coffee`:

```
$(document).ready ->
  $('p:first').fadeIn()
```

However, if I do this:

```
$(document).ready ->
  alert($('p:first').text())
```

I do get the correct text.  Can anyone tell me what is going on here?

THANK YOU EVERYONE, and thanks Trevor for reading my mind. Thanks Benoit for helping me to properly use the site.  My final answer below.

Comment: Is your p:first hidden on page load?

Comment: More precisely: *How* is it hidden? With `visibility: hidden` or `display: none`?

Comment: Thank you guys.  Trevor nailed it.  Visibility:hidden doesn't work but display:none does. Thank You!

Comment: @loucal you can put the solution in an aswer instead of putting it in the question. You can even accept your own answer afterwards.

Comment: Thanks Benoit, I have the answer all typed and ready to go but I need to wait 3 more hours to post it because I'm a noob.

Comment: @loucal you should be able to now, and you don't really need to put a thank you paragraph at the end upvotes are a better way to show you appreciation if it's a proper answer.

Comment: Benoit, I have to wait 25 minutes from now it still says.  Also, I can't upvote anything because my rep is too low. Thanks for the tip though, I will keep that in mind for when I can upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dug around a bit and found this: (from http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)

> Elements with visibility: hidden or opacity: 0 are considered to be visible, since they still consume space in the layout. During animations that hide an element, the element is considered to be visible until the end of the animation. During animations to show an element, the element is considered to be visible at the start at the animation.
>
> How :visible is calculated was changed in jQuery 1.3.2. The release notes outline the changes in more detail.

So, using the correct style, or the toggle functions in jQuery are the right option.